# how to get the key of an item of the array inside foreach loop in php

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

Below is the example of the array that I have.

```
  Array (
[952] => Array ( [Date] => 2016-06-23 01:55:17 [SValues] => Array ( [total] => 1 [Name] => Name [OverAge] => No))
[91] => Array ( [Date] => 2016-06-23 01:55:17 [SValues] => Array ( [total] => 1  [Name] => Name [OverAge] => No))
[83] => Array ( [Date] => 2016-06-23 01:55:17 [SValues] => Array ( [total] => 1 [Name] => Name [OverAge] => No)))
```

And then, I put this array inside the foreach loop.

```
foreach($the-main-array as $item)
{
          //I want to get the key of the item here (952,91,83)
}
```

So how can I get the key of the item inside the loop?

Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Go look at the `foreach()` manual page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to specify a variable to store the key in as part of your `foreach` loop setup. You can do that like this:

```
foreach($the-main-array as $key => $item){
    echo "This is the key: ".$key;
}
```

For clarity, you can call the `$key` variable anything you like. It doesn't have to be `$key`.

---

**Related reading:**

- [foreach PHP Docs](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)
- [Alternative Control Structures](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php) are not directly related but a lot of people miss out on them because they are unaware it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

Use This,

```
foreach($the-main-array as $key => $item)
{
// Put your code here.
// $key have the key value.

}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
foreach($mainArray as $k => $item){
    $k is the key
    $item is the value
}
```